# Install additional node versions in Plesk Onyx

Tags: node.js, meteor, plesk, nvm

**This a guidance not a problem to solve, to help those which have the same issue I had**

Enable Node support in Plesk Onyx:

1. Install the ["Node support"](https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/node-js-plesk-onyx/) simply from your "update and updates" Plesk interface.
2. Go to your ["Node extension" page](https://ext.plesk.com/packages/1e47ed49-bca9-46d6-8828-7d3c42a2f21b-nodejs) enable/disable the node versions you need

In case you need additional node versions which does not come with the default node support installation:

1. Install the [**N**ode **V**ersion **M**anager](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) on your server
2. Install the versions you need e.g. `nvm install v4.8.4`
3. Copy paste the node version to plesk `cp -R ~/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/ /opt/plesk/node/`
4. Then notify your plesk about your installation `plesk sbin nodemng register /opt/plesk/node/v4.8.4/bin/node`
5. Go to your node extension page where all node versions are listed, hit refresh and voilá

I had some troubles installing additional node versions into Plesk to run my meteorJS app on my server instead of their hosting service.

Comment: what's the problem ?

Comment: Actually just a guidance, actual response is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44131956/how-to-add-a-new-node-js-version-for-the-node-js-manager-on-plesk/

Comment: @Maertz You're the first person I've found who has posted an answer to a question that combines Plesk and Meteor. I'm guessing that you have experience in getting Meteor to run on a server mananged by Plesk. Would you have some time to talk me through the process? I've set up a chat room where you can join me: chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157298/meteor-and-plesk

Comment: The chat is closed, let me know when it's reopened.

Comment: Should probably make this a Q/A not an answer without a question

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question :)
As some people were using this method, they ran into this problem:

```
/opt/plesk/node/v12.13.1/bin/npm install
/usr/bin/env: 'node': No such file or directory
```

The NPM script is looking for the default node location by asking it to `env`.
The plesk-version of the NPM files are slightly modified to point to the correct node version.

To fix this, make a small edit to the npm file:

- After step 3, edit the `/opt/plesk/node/[your_version]/bin/npm` file.
- Replace the first line with `#!/opt/plesk/node/[your_version]/bin/node`

Answer (score 1):

Everything worked for me except for the original step 4. I got the following error:

```
Unknown Plesk command-line utility: "nodemng"
```

I found a workaround using the GUI Plesk extention called "Node.js Toolkit". I have replaced the original step 4 with a new process:

1. Install the [**N**ode **V**ersion **M**anager] on your server
2. Install the versions you need e.g. `nvm install v4.8.4`
3. Copy paste the node version to plesk `cp -R ~/.nvm/versions/node/v4.8.4/ /opt/plesk/node/`
4. **Open the Node.js Toolkit (available from inside Extentions) and hit the Refresh button**

Your new Node version should now be selectable from the dropdown of options when starting your Node app via the GUI.

Hope this helps someone.