# Plesk npm 12 installed, but showing 6.9.0

Tags: node.js, linux, plesk

I have installed Node.js from upgrade/install packages without any problems, but when I try to run the following: `/opt/plesk/node/12/bin/node -v` the output i get is:

> 12.4.0

The problem is that when I try to install authentication with Bootstrap for Laravel, and I get to the point where I need to run: `npm install && npm run dev` I get the following error when running `/opt/plesk/node/12/bin/npm run dev`:

> Error: You are using an unspported version of Node. Please update to
> at least Node v12.14

It seems like I a'm running the newest version, but it still complaints about wrong version number? - How to fix?

UPDATE (debug log):

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/opt/plesk/node/12/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/opt/plesk/node/12/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.4.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
6 info lifecycle @~dev: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: /opt/plesk/node/12/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs2/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/us$
9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs2
10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run development' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `npm run development`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/opt/plesk/node/12/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:200:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/plesk/node/12/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs2
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-126-generic
17 verbose argv "/opt/plesk/node/12/bin/node" "/opt/plesk/node/12/bin/npm" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v12.4.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ dev: `npm run development`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: You did `npm -v`, not `node -v`. NPM and Node versions aren't the same.

Comment: Okay, how do I test what version of Node I am using?

Comment: I don't use plesk so I can just guess: `/opt/plesk/node/12/bin/node -v`

Comment: Aah, Node just take one -, not two --. I a'm using version 12.4.0, hmmm strange

Comment: Yea sorry, that was a typo. But that seems to be the problem. Look at what NPM says: "`Please update to at least Node v12.14.0`". You're currently running v12.4.0. That's 10 minor versions behind.

Comment: Aha! I properly need to install it manually, can't seem to update the Node version with Plesk, but I will keep investigating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A big thanks to NullDev for leading me in the right direction!

I found the answer here: [How to add a new node.js version for the Node.js Manager on Plesk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44131956/how-to-add-a-new-node-js-version-for-the-node-js-manager-on-plesk)

1. We need to install Node Version Manager
2. Then install whatever version we want (I wanted the newest one v14.15.4)
3. We then copy that version to Plesk default Node versions path
4. And finally we tell Plesk about the newly version created
5. Then in the list of all versions installed, we refresh and voila, we now have support for v14.15.4

Credit for this goes to Maertz