# How to add a new NodeJS version for the Node.js Manager on Plesk Obsidian?

Tags: node.js, centos7, plesk, obsidian

Since **Plesk Obsidian** (v18.x) it doesn't work like the procedure from [this answer (Plesk Onyx)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46846077/10824494) and now I am not able to add new versions of NodeJS.

```
plesk sbin nodemng register /opt/plesk/node/18/bin/node​
```

This command line return this error and Plesk do not register this new version of NodeJS 18.15.0: `Unknown Plesk command-line utility: "nodemng"`

Any ideas how to proceed now with Plesk Obsidian ?

Many thanks for your help.

### I've tried successfully in the past with Plesk Onyx, but now with Obsidian it seems something change to **register** new versions to Plesk with "nodemng" command-line utility.

OS: Centos7

Comment: did you figure this one out, issue I have right now for centos

Comment: Make sure you have upgraded to ubuntu 20, if you are still on ubuntu 18, the plesk node extension will not install node 18 and node 20