# How to add/upgrade node.js on Plesk Obsidian

Tags: node.js, plesk

I have tried to update node.js in Plesk Obsidian.
I can only find older tutorials that no longer work with Obsidian. The Plesk Support has also provided limited assistance. I was able to install node.js v20 via SSH and copy it to the directory
`opt/plesk/node/20`

The instructions now say that I should execute the following command:

`plesk sbin nodemng register /opt/plesk/node/20/bin/node`

This is met with the following error message:
`Unknown Plesk command-line utility: "nodemng"`
However, another command `plesk ext nodejs --install -version v20.0.0`  would also result in an error message. Namely: `The Node.js version "v20.0.0plesk" was not found.`

I'm running out of ideas and I don't know what else I could do to upgrade node.js from 16.4 to v20. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a new node.js version for the Node.js Manager on Plesk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44131956/how-to-add-a-new-node-js-version-for-the-node-js-manager-on-plesk)

Comment: Also a duplicate of this more recent question with no answer yet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75984537/how-to-add-a-new-nodejs-version-for-the-node-js-manager-on-plesk-obsidian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now tried many suggestions, but until today, I have not been able to install Node.js v18 or 20.
I have found an interesting article that explains why it is not possible.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/43246

There, the following is being said:

> One good reason for dropping support for CentOS/RHEL 7 is glibc. CentOS 7 ships with glibc 2.17 but node's dependencies are moving to newer versions.

Thatswhy newer versions of node are not supported until CentOs update GLIBC to 2.27.
Ubuntu 18.04 ships with glibc 2.27.

For now we have to wait until CentOs is updated or another workaround was found.

I hope some others need this information as helpful, so they can stop searching here. I will update this answer if there is anything new.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I've been struggling with the exact same issue as you, trying to update my Plesk's Node version to register v20 & v18, ending up down the same rabbitholes. It looks like I need to hold off on releasing the update of my app until this is addressed...

Comment: I switched to ubuntu now. Here its no problem to update to all new versions. Maybe u have to switch too. Its one time hard work, but in the future its all easier to handle given packages.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `nodemng` utility was removed from Plesk Obsidian although it is not referenced in the documentation for Onyx either.

Additionally, the `nodejs` extension does not offer functionality to install new NodeJS versions but only to manage the existing ones. Check the [documentation](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/cli-linux/using-command-line-utilities/nodejs-nodejs-versions.77392/) for the supported arguments.

Finally, in [this](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/12377465555863) question is mentioned that:

> The Node.js extension now automatically installs and updates supported LTS versions.

So I guess we will have to wait until NodeJS v20 gains LTS status.

Comment: the node js extension is not even installing the v18 lts

Comment: What is the output of `plesk ext nodejs --versions`?

Comment: it will output outdated versions but the folder /opt/plesk/node/18 exists

Comment: Make sure you have upgraded to ubuntu 20, if you are still on ubuntu 18, the plesk node extension will not install node 18 and node 20 as indicated in the changelog